# How to create a task that watches the size of a file in a c# console application

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project that will need to create text files and fill them with guids using an array of 25 tasks. I want to use another task separate from the writing tasks to monitor the size of the file at 0.5 second intervals.

I'm struggling to figure out a way to do this. I know with a C# WPF application I could use the FILEIO class but I don't think I have access to that using a console app.

What could I use instead of the FILEIO class to create this task and how would I create it?

Comment: There is no "FILEIO" class. There is a `File` class, which is included in `System.IO` and can be used with any mainstream framework. However using the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0) class would probably be better than querying the file info every half second. But at the same time, this task to write to the file is running in the same assembly as the task to monitor it right? Why can't you just make these two tasks communicate? That would probably be the simpler solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no system-provided class class named `FILEIO`; system-provided classes use consistent naming. Might you mean `System.IO.FileInfo` perhaps? Is there a reason you want an array of 25 Tasks? That seems weirdly specific early in the design process. The trick with a console app is keeping the process running while you asynchronous work completes

Comment: It's worth noting that my solution will create 25 text files, each containing 1000 stringified GUIDs in about 0.45 to 0.7 seconds. Reporting every half second, doesn't yield much useful info. Also, in my solution, I don't measure file size, I count how much information has been written.  If I went to the file system to measure this, I suspect that I'd end up measuring the cost of doing the measurement. There's also the question of possible locking issues from looking at file info while writing to the file. Also, reporting progress on 25 operations from within a console app is hard

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new `Thread` and use the `Length` property of a `System.IO.FileInfo` object to get the size of a file.

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-6.0) for more details on Threading.

Comment: Why is a new thread necessary? The OP didn't mention anything about multithreading. Can you include a code snippet showing how your solution solves the question asked?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.  Everything is asynchronous.  The only thread created monitors the count (so that you can see what's going on - which is the point of this, I think).

First I create a class like this:

```
internal class GuidWriter
{
    public string Folder { get; }
    public string FileNamePattern { get; }
    public int CountOfFiles { get; }
    public int CountOfGuids { get; }
    public int TotalGuidsToWrite { get; }

    private int _currentGuidCount = 0;
    public int CurrentGuidCount { get { return _currentGuidCount; } }

    public GuidWriter(string folder, string fileNamePattern, int countOfFiles, int countOfGuids)
    {
        Folder = folder;
        FileNamePattern = fileNamePattern;
        CountOfFiles = countOfFiles;
        CountOfGuids = countOfGuids;
        TotalGuidsToWrite = countOfFiles * countOfGuids;
    }

    public async Task WriteAllFiles()
    {
        var writeTaskList = new List<Task>(CountOfFiles);
        for (int i = 0; i < CountOfFiles; i++)
        {
            var writeTask = WriteGuidsToOneFile(i + 1);
            writeTaskList.Add(writeTask);
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(writeTaskList);
    }

    private async Task WriteGuidsToOneFile(int fileNumber)
    {
        var fileName = string.Format(FileNamePattern, fileNumber);
        var filePathName = Path.Combine(Folder, fileName);
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePathName))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < CountOfGuids; ++i)
            {
                var guidString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(guidString);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentGuidCount);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You create one of these things, tell it how it should work (in the constructor) and then let it rip in the `WriteAllFiles` (which is async, and which you should await).

It uses `Interlocked.Increment` on the Guid count - if the framework doesn't anything in threads, I want to make sure that I don't mess up the count.

Then in the main program, I create a Monitor function that counts the number of Guids created and outputs them to the console.  It runs in a separate thread, and will go away when it's *CancellationToken* is canceled:

```
public static async Task MonitorGuidProduction (GuidWriter guidWriter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var monitorString = $"{guidWriter.CurrentGuidCount}/{guidWriter.TotalGuidsToWrite}";
        Console.WriteLine(monitorString);
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

Then, in the main program, I put it all together:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var cancelToken = cancelTokenSource.Token;
        var folder = @"C:\temp\guids";
        var pattern = "GuidFile{0}.txt";
        var guidWriter = new GuidWriter(folder, pattern, CountOfFiles, CountOfGuids);
        var monitorTask = Task.Run(() => MonitorGuidProduction(guidWriter, cancelToken));
        await guidWriter.WriteAllFiles();
        
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();

        await monitorTask;

        Console.WriteLine($"{guidWriter.CurrentGuidCount} Guids written to {CountOfFiles} files");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I create an instance of a `GuidWriter` and, just before I let it go (by calling  `guidWriter.WriteAllFiles`, I start up my monitor function in another thread.  I do that by running Task.Run, but not awaiting its result until everything else is done (getting the cleanup just right).

Then I await the call to `guidWriter.WriteAllFiles`, and when it completes, I signal my cancellation token to stop the monitor task/thread.